# array_reshape() with strange behaviour

Tags: r, keras, reticulate

for reshaping an array I use array_reshape() from reticulate package. For some purposes, I need a pre-allocated array consisting only of NA. Now let's see what array_reshape() does.

```
data <- c(NA, NA, NA)
a <- as.array(data)
a <- reticulate::array_reshape(a, dim = c(1L, 1L, 3L), order = "F")
```

The result of a is:

```
logi[1, 1, 1:3] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

To get a comparison for this column-major ordering style (Fortran-style) using dim() leads to a different result

```
data <- c(NA, NA, NA)
a <- as.array(data)
dim(a) <- c(1L, 1L, 3L)
```

The result of a is how expected:

```
logi[1, 1, 1:3] NA NA NA
```

After further tests I found out that NA is transferred to TRUE if there is no numeric or alphanumeric (e.g. character) value in the array. If a e.g. numeric value is in the array all worked as expected

```
data <- c(NA, NA, 3)
a <- as.array(data)
a <- reticulate::array_reshape(a, dim = c(1L, 1L, 3L), order = "F")
```

```
logi[1, 1, 1:3] NA NA 3
```

But, if using logical values in the array too, the result will be

```
data <- c(NA, NA, FALSE)
a <- as.array(data)
a <- reticulate::array_reshape(a, dim = c(1L, 1L, 3L), order = "F")
```

```
logi[1, 1, 1:3] TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

That's in my opinion very "dangerous" because later no distinction can be made whether the original value is NA or logical TRUE. Using dim() always leads to results as expected.

PS: I know that internally a NA is treated as a logical constant of length 1.

Do you have any hints or suggestions to solve this reshaping issue with array_reshape()?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may be relevant https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/197 and `data <- c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)` gives expected, but then `data <- c(NA_real_, NA_real_, FALSE)` converts the `FALSE` to `0`, and `data <- c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)` is not great.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link you provided.